# How do I get a SearchBar in a TableView to look like the one in the Settings App

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uisearchbar

In my app I have a TableView that is searchable with a SearBar on top. I added the SearchBar, by dragging one in via the Interface Builder and then making my TableView a UISearchBarDelegate and adding:

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

This results in the following look

[image]

What I do want is my SearchBar to look like the one in the Settings App (the one preinstalled on every iOS device) that looks like this

[image]

Also, when clicked on, it behaves differently, in that it greys out the rest of the view and removes the title as seen here

[image]

Whereas my SearchBar only opens the keyboard and shows a cursor when clicked on.

What do I need to do to achieve this specific look and feel?

Comment: You need to start by setting the search bar controller to the `navigationItem` - [`UINavigationItem#searchController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller)

Comment: Maybe [Large Title and Search in iOS 11](https://medium.com/@PavelGnatyuk/large-title-and-search-in-ios-11-514d5e020cee) and/or [Large Titles For Navigation Bars In iOS 11](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/large-titles-ios-11/) can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily by adding UISearchController to navigationBar programmatically. Create UISearchController by using code :

`let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`

then add it to navigationItem,

```
    controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    controller.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
    definesPresentationContext = true
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.searchController = controller
    } else {
        navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```

Credit : https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `UISearchBar` by making a subclass of it:

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        self.placeholder = "Search"

        // Color of the text field (in your case it should be gray)
        self.barTintColor = yourGraySearchBarColor

        // Color of the cursor (you don't need to change this if you want to stay with the default blue)
        self.tintColor = UIColor.white

        // Background color of you search bar
        self.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "SearchBarBG")
    }
}
```

To set the background color of your search bar, you have to create an image, which is a square with only your wanted color (in your case light gray), size does not matter, I would set it to 20x20 px.

You can darken the background by adding a semi-transparent gray UIView above the whole screen (except the SearchBar, so it needs to be under the SearchBar). If you adopt `UISearchBarDelegate` you can add this overlay in the `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)` function and remove it in the `searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)` function.